# SSRS Parameters multi value problem (select all does not work)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a parameter 'Catégorie de vente' which contains two values 'Déchets and No Sans déchets', the problem is that when I click on select all, it just selects me the first value 'Déchets ' the other not.

**Here is the parameter**

[image]

**And here is the request**

[image]

Any heeelp pleaseee!!!!
Why selecting all does not work

Comment: Why use a query for 2 values? Why not just use the specific values option and put `Déchets` and `No Sans déchets` in there?

Comment: Also, neither of those images show what you're doing to select all (both) the values. have you actually enabled multiple selections in your parameter's options?

Comment: I did it but in vain :( always it shows me just 'Déchets' when I click on Select all

Comment: @Larnu can you help me please!

Comment: A few questions: 1. Does your parameter query actually return both values. 2. What happens if you choose each parameter value individually, do you get the expected results? 3. What does your main dataset query look like, in particular, the WHERE clause ?

Comment: You don't need to shout(!) at me. And you didn't actually respond to my comment(s) @BasmaLachhab ... Help *me* help **you**.

Comment: Here is the where clause:                                                                                    

WHERE F_DOCLIGNE.DO_Type IN (3, 4, 5, 6, 7) AND (LEFT(dbo.F_FAMILLE.FA_CodeFamille, 2) IN ('90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '99')) AND F_FAMILLE.fa_codefamille IN (@prmCat)

Comment: what about my first two questions?